# What's the name of the character `*`?

Tags: word-choice

We can see the character or symbol `*` on web pages or in code.

What's its name?

1. From my dictionary, it is called the *asterisk*.
2. But in the [documentation page](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html) of fishshell dot com, it is called the *star* or *star character*.

So which one is correct and what's the difference between them? When you see `*`, what's the first word that appears in your mind?

Comment: I would always refer to it as an asterisk. That would be the correct name. However, it is also perfectly understandable (if simplistic) to refer to it as a "star".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either term is acceptable.

I generally call it by its formal name, *asterisk*. But 'star character' is becoming common; we speak of *starring* a passage when we put an asterisk in the margin; and in fact the name *asterisk* is, etymologically, *little star*, from Greek via Latin.

Comment: Spelling note: remember to spell it with "isk". Using "ix" is based on a [fictional character with pseudo-Gallish spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix)